# Update using razor pages

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

How to achieve the following using Razor Pages:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET Verify = 'D' WHERE Tag_No = txtTag
```

(where txtTag is a string from the input tag on the index page).

Comment: What has your research shown you? This is a very common scenario... its been solved multiple times before...

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to cover to achieve this.  I'd suggest working through a tutorial for an application that goes through setting up the project, hooking up the UI to the backend, and handling data in a database.

Something like this, which is the getting started guide for ASP.NET MVC 5 from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I was not that convoluted, I've done it, it took a lot of time and trial-and-error but here is the code:

```
//Index.cshtml

<form id="formTagNo" method="post" asp-page-handler="Tagno">
   <label for="Tag_No">Tag No. </label>
   <input type="text" asp-for="TxtTag" onchange="$('#formTagNo').submit();" />
</form>
```

```
//Index.cshtml.cs

[BindProperty]
public Inventory MyInventory { get; set; }
public string TxtTag { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostTagnoAsync(string TxtTag)
{
  MyInventory = await _context.Inventory.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Tag_No == TxtTag);
  MyInventory.Verify = "D";
  _context.Attach(MyInventory).State = EntityState.Modified;
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```